# Unable to create a debug configuration for Protractor in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, webstorm

I'm trying to create a debug configuration for an E2E testing app based on Protractor. The actual script reads command line arguments while executing the test and I'm not sure how to implement this in the debug configuration so I'm able to execute tests using the execute button available on my 'it' blocks.

[image]

[image]

Would really appreciate it if someone could guide me through creating the configuration file to help me debug.

Comment: haven't got what you mean... Can you run your tests using the run config for 'all tests' shown on your screenshot? Please share a sample project with similar setup, otherwise it's not clear what it looks like and what problems running tests you have faced

Answer (score 0):

I add the debug configurations inside my `package.json`, under the scripts section:

```
"debug": "node --inspect-brk ./node_modules/.bin/protractor protractor.conf.js",
```

For more reference head over to the `package.json` on my github repo: https://github.com/BhattcharyaCodes/skeletal/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Okay, I understand this step. This attaches a debugger. How do you run the tests in debug mode? If you are using an IDE, do you use any additional configurations?